# Systemd Timer every minute on specific hours (using a range of values)

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

I want a script to run minutely, but stop executing it during the nighttime.

I tried

```
OnCalendar=*-*-* 05..00:*:00
```

but that lead to

```
Failed to parse calendar specification, ignoring: *-*-* 05..00:*:00
Timer unit lacks value setting. Refusing
```

Whats wrong here?

Comment: If [this fix](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3042) didn't make it into your version of systemd, try the workaround of specifying each allowable hour separated by a comma.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using an invalid time range.  When using `BEGIN..END`, `END` must be later than `BEGIN`. Obviously, `00` is earlier than `05` so `05..00` errors out. You need

```
OnCalendar=*-*-* 05..23:*:00
```

This will run your script every minute from `05:00` until `23:59`. I assume that was your intent. If instead you wanted to run from `05:00` until `0:59` you would use

```
OnCalendar=*-*-* 00,05..23:*:00
```

Answer (score -1):

Taken from the systemd.time man page:

```
*-*-* 03-05:*:00
```

The above example would cause the systemd managed script to run every minute between the hours of 03 and 05

Comment: This does not seem to solve the problem, I still get the output `Failed to parse calendar specification, ignoring: *-*-* 05-00:*:00`

Comment: @don_crissti `systemd --version`
`systemd 232`

Comment: As don_crissti points out, your example is not a direct quote from the man page, and is invalid syntax. This answer should be removed.