# How to indicate hour range in Timer using OnCalendar?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, systemctl, systemd-timer

systemd 219 version

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

```
[Unit]
Description=Run myscript.service every 5 minutes

[Timer]
OnCalendar= *-*-* 10-23:10/5:00
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

I need to run my service every hour past 10 minutes until 23:10. (10:10, 11:10, 12:10 ..23:10). I face difficulty in indicating the hours range.

I have tried **10-23, 10..23** even pasted the same date from another [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438505/systemd-timer-every-minute-on-specific-hours-using-a-range-of-values). Still did not work.

Error

```
Dec 27 16:48:09 node1 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/myscript.timer:5] Failed to parse calendar specification, ignoring: *-*-* 10..23:10/5:00
Dec 27 16:48:09 node1 systemd[1]: myscript.timer lacks value setting. Refusing.
Dec 27 16:52:51 node1 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/myscript.timer:5] Failed to parse calendar specification, ignoring: *-*-*10..23:10/5:00
Dec 27 16:52:51 node1 systemd[1]: myscript.timer lacks value setting. Refusing.
Dec 27 16:55:18 node1 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/myscript.timer:5] Failed to parse calendar specification, ignoring: *-*-* 9-17:00:00
Dec 27 16:55:18 node1 systemd[1]: myscript.timer lacks value setting. Refusing.
Dec 27 16:56:45 node1 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/myscript.timer:5] Failed to parse calendar specification, ignoring: *-*-* 9-18:00:00
Dec 27 16:56:45 node1 systemd[1]: myscript.timer lacks value setting. Refusing.
Dec 27 16:57:59 node1 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/myscript.timer:5] Failed to parse calendar specification, ignoring: *-*-* 10-23:10/5:00
Dec 27 16:57:59 node1 systemd[1]: myscript.timer lacks value setting. Refusing.
```

Answer (score 1):

Support for the `x..y` syntax for time ranges was only added in [systemd version 231](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/74ce6bbdee7ab77f770c1caade304484c167e63f/NEWS#L10577).

```
CHANGES WITH 231:

        * Calendar time specifications in .timer units now understand a ".."
          syntax for time ranges. Example: "4..7:10" may now be used for
          defining a timer that is triggered at 4:10am, 5:10am, 6:10am and
          7:10am every day.
```

With older versions, you'll need to specify multiple `OnCalendar=` settings, one for each hour – or change the script itself to check current time and immediately exit if outside the interval.